# ngView and ngInclude in the same SPA, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

I have a question that won't take much of your time.

In AngularJS, we create a SPA that uses ngView along with ngInclude.
We click a link to add /contact to the URL, making the View to update and change content. Does the ngInclude content updates too?(Reloading and Showing the same content)

Thank you.

Comment: This question is hard to understand. Could you include an example and correct the language as best as possible?